# How can I increase my reputation if I can't answer and I can't vote?

Tags: support, reputation

I wasn't active on Stack Overflow for a long time. When I wanted to vote or to post for some question or to leave a comment I found that I have a low reputation. Unfortunately I didn't research a way except to ask questions. Is there any way to increase my reputation?

Comment: You said that you "can't answer". Do you mean that you don't know enough to answer any of the questions, or are you getting a specific message from the site saying that you are not allowed to answer anymore?

Answer (score 5):

No, asking a well received question is not the only way to gain reputation.

You can also post a well received answer. I would guess that that is the most common way to gain reputation score.